# Linear maps ranks: true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f: V \rightarrow U$ and $g: U \rightarrow W$ two linear maps. Then

$$\operatorname{rk}(f\circ g) = \min\bigl\{\operatorname{rk}(f),\operatorname{rk}(g)\bigr\}$$

$$\operatorname{rk}(g\circ f) \le \operatorname{rk}(f)$$

Are these statements true or false? Prove them.

Comment: What's rg?  Do you mean rank?

Comment: Consider this: is there any way for the kernel to get smaller with each successive map?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your order of functions is incorrect, since the range of $g$ is different of the domain of $f$. I'll assume the following: $f: V \to W$ and $g: U \to V$.

Although the first statement is not true, the statement $\operatorname{rk}(fg) \leq \min{\{ \operatorname{rk}(f), \operatorname{rk}(g) \} }$ is true (maybe it was a typo?).

The statements $\operatorname{rk}(fg) \leq \operatorname{rk}(g)$ and $\operatorname{rk}(fg) \leq\operatorname{rk}(f)$ together imply the above statement. The first is true because the image of $fg$ is actually $f(\operatorname{im}(g))$, since $fg(U) = f(g(U)) = f(\operatorname{im}(g))$. This image of $g$ is a subspace of $V$, and we can write $\operatorname{im}(g) \oplus T = V$, where $T$ denotes the complement.

Note that, by the definition of the image of $f$, we can write:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname{im}(f) = f(V) = \{ f(v) \mid v \in V \}  = \{ f(s + t) \mid s + t \in \operatorname{im}(g) \oplus T \} \\
= \{ f(s) + f(t) \mid s \in \operatorname{im}(g), t \in T \} = f(\operatorname{im}(g)) + f(T) \supseteq f(\operatorname{im}(g)) = f(g(U)) = \operatorname{im}(fg)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Hence, the image of $fg$ is a subspace of the image of $f$, so it cannot have a higher dimension than the image of $f$.

For the second statement, since $\operatorname{im}(g)$ is a subspace of $V$, we define the restriction $\left. f \right|_{\operatorname{im}(g)}: \operatorname{im}(g) \to W$. Note that $\operatorname{im}(fg) = f(\operatorname{im}(g)) = \left. f \right|_{\operatorname{im}(g)} (\operatorname{im}(g))$.

Remember, by the rank-nullity theorem, that, since $\operatorname{im}(g)$ is the domain:
\begin{equation}
\dim(\operatorname{im}(g)) = \operatorname{rk}(g) = \operatorname{rk}(\left. f \right|_{\operatorname{im}(g)}) + \operatorname{null}(\left. f \right|_{\operatorname{im}(g)}) \; ,
\end{equation}
so we have $\operatorname{rk}(\left. f \right|_{\operatorname{im}(g)}) \leq \operatorname{rk}(g)$, and since
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{rk}(\left. f \right|_{\operatorname{im}(g)}) = \dim(f(\operatorname{im}(g))) = \dim(fg(U)) = \operatorname{rk}(fg) \; ,
\end{equation}
the equality holds for the image of $fg$, and the second part is proved.

We have that $\operatorname{rk}(fg) \leq \operatorname{rk}(g)$ and $\operatorname{rk}(fg) \leq\operatorname{rk}(f)$, hence $\operatorname{rk}(fg) \leq \min{\{ \operatorname{rk}(f), \operatorname{rk}(g) \} }$.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is false .  Take $f(x,y)=(0,y), g(x,y)=(x,0)$.

The second is true.  By the rank nullity theorem, linear transformations don't increase dimension, so to speak.